# Retrofit returns HTTP 401 for call running in background

Tags: android, networking, background, retrofit2

I have a strange problem with one of my retrofit call,it works fine when the app is in the background(recent list)

I have a call through which i update my widget data,the problem is when the app is cleared of from the recent list,the call gives HTTP 401 unauthorized response.

however i pass the same bearer token with it.

please have a look at the code and suggest some help

```
public static OkHttpClient getOkhttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + TokenGenerator.getToken())
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    }).build();

    return client;
}

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(getOkhttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Comment: At what point in your code are you making this call?

Comment: If you are getting success in the background(recent list) and postman, then the surly problem is with passing token. Please try filter log in Android studio with *Authorization* when your app is not in recent.

Comment: Yes, exactly...that was the problem...I solved it :)

Comment: Good. if you are feel it's help to other developer please post answer for the same.

Comment: The story is like  this : the previous developer stored the token in a static variable..

as usual when memory gets cleared,it used to send null..

I fixed this by saving it in preferences